# MVC5 Remote Validation + Additional Data from Server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is it possible in MVC5 to remote validate a field but to return additional data in my JSON result? As e.g. a suggested value for the field? All examples I have seen only return true or false (whether or not the field is valid) but I need a little bit more info to populate additional fields. Apart from that, how would I catch that additional data in the client side?

I just do not want to go twice to the server, i.e., once to validate the field and an additional travel to bring the additional data back.

Comment: What's your existing code look like? You can pack whatever you like into a JSON result

Comment: Yes, you can return more than true or false. [Here's an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(vs.98).aspx#Anchor_0) that either returns true, or return a string to suggest a different username.

Comment: Thank you that is actually what I needed.